# sweating and body fat

Tags: body-fat

I am 49 yrs old and I am in very good shape. While taking a cycling class at the gym today someone commented on how much I was sweating. The instructor chimed in ad made the comment that I need to lose fat to keep from seating so much. Is this true.

Like I said I am in very good shape and I am not fat by any strtch of the imagination. I am 6'1 and 201 lbs. I exercise 5 to 6 days a week, and do a lot of cardio.

Comment: Next time, ask the instructor why he/she assumed you're fat. Sweating can be caused by many factors, including your intensity and room's temperature. Maybe you're trying too hard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons you may of been sweating more.
One, you could simply of been working harder than others.  If you are fit, you probably know how to push yourself harder in training.

Too much Caffine or alcohol.

Fat is the bodies natural insulator, and sweating is the bodies means of cooling you down.  So in some cases what the instructor said could be true.  However, if you don't carry extra fat, this sounds like a very irresponsible thing for the instructor to of said.  In your case it seems unlikely to be the course.

If you are concerned then seek medical advice.  It never hurts to get these things checked out

Answer (score 1):

Sweating is what your body does when it needs to cool down.  There can be many causes of having more relative sweat than others:

- Excessive body fat--we're talking 30% or more for men
- More muscle mass--muscles use more energy and as it burns energy it gets warmer
- Genetics--some people just sweat more when all other factors are the same

There is no one definitive reason why one person would sweat more than another.  The more mass you have the harder your body has to work to move it.  That's the same whether you have excess fat or more muscle than the other person.  Stimulants like caffeine can cause your body to burn nervous energy, which might increase the sweat a little, but if the cause of sweat is exercise it's likely differences in mass and genetics.